# How to create a counter with a plus and minus button which passes a parameter so that I don't have two use two separate functions?

Tags: javascript

I have created a counter with a plus and minus button. The counter works fine but I would like to simplify my code by passing a parameter to my function that performs both the plus and minus calculations depending on which button is clicked. At the moment I have two separate functions doing this but I would like to pass the 'result' variable as this is the part that tells my script whether I want to add 1 or minus 1, however I am unsure on how to do this?

I have attached my JavaScript below to show what I have so far.

```
document.getElementById('minus').onclick = function() {
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
    var parsed = parseInt(counter);
    var result = parsed -1;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = result;
}

document.getElementById('plus').onclick = function() {
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
    var parsed = parseInt(counter);
    var result = parsed +1;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a curried function to "bake" your delta value into the click handlers:

```
function changeCount(delta) {
   return function () {
       var counter = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
       var parsed = parseInt(counter);
       var result = parsed + delta;
       document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = result;
   } 
}

document.getElementById('minus').onclick = changeCount(-1);
document.getElementById('plus').onclick = changeCount(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same function to modify the counter element and then just pass a negative or positive integer as the parameter to the function, like so:

```
document.getElementById('minus').onclick = modifyCount(-1);

document.getElementById('plus').onclick = modifyCount(1); 

//Just pass the integer into the function to modify the counter element
function modifyCount(val){
    const counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `curried` functions.

The following should make your code simple and as required:

```
function getCounter(multiplier = 1) {
    return function () {
       var counter = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
       var parsed = parseInt(counter);
       var result = parsed + (multiplier * 1);
       document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = result;
    }
}

document.getElementById('minus').onclick = getCounter(-1);

document.getElementById('plus').onclick = getCounter(); // 1 is the default value
```

Curried functions are basically, functions that return another function. The inner functions have access to the variables defined in the wrapping function. read more about them here: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983

Comment: Why "multiplier"?  Why multiply that value by 1 (a no-op)?  Why name the "addOrSubtract"? Shouldn't it be something like "changeCounter"?  See the answer from Ned Howley for the same idea but without these oddities.

Comment: The `1` is to prevent an `undefined` which would ultimately yield a `NaN`. you're probably right about the function name. Updated the answer :)

Comment: It's not a big deal, but even "getCounter" is a strange name for a function whose job it is to *update*/*change*/*modify* the counter.  (See other answers for the use of those names.)  I have no problem with the (new?) default value.  What I was objecting to is `result = parsed + (multiplier * 1)`, instead of something like `result = parsed + delta`.  I don't know what that multiplication is doing there, and I still don't understand why you name the variable "multiplier" when what you're doing with it is adding it to the current value.

Comment: Ahhh! I see what you're saying. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution with onclick event:

```js
  function count(clicked_id)
  {
  var counter = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
    var parsed = parseInt(counter);
      let result = clicked_id == "minus" ? parsed - 1 : parsed + 1;
      document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = result;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="count(this.id)" id="minus">-</button>
<div id="counter">0</div>
<button onclick="count(this.id)" id="plus">+</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first and only parameter of the click handler, to get the ID of the element. Then use a ternary command to decide, if the result should be incremented or decremented.

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
    var parsed = parseInt(counter);
    var result = e.target.id === 'plus' ? parsed + 1 : parsed - 1;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = result;
}

document.getElementById('minus').onclick = clickHandler;
document.getElementById('plus').onclick = clickHandler;
```

You could also rewrite the method to use an `if` instead of the `result` variable.

Here's what I would consider an optimized version:

```
const counterElem = document.getElementById('counter');

function clickHandler(e) {
    counterElem.innerHTML =
        parseInt(counterElem.innerHTML) +
        (e.target.id === 'plus' ? 1 : -1);
}

document.getElementById('minus').onclick = clickHandler;
document.getElementById('plus').onclick = clickHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to a function, you just need to use that function on the event you want.

```
function counterFunction(action) {
 var counter = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
 var parsed = parseInt(counter);
 var result = '';
  if (action == 'minus') {
    result = parsed -1;
  }
  else if (action == 'plus') {
    result = parsed +1;
  }
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = result;
}
```

If you need any help please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Button tag call the below method in OnClick event
2. In **'action'** parameter , pass the button value as '+' or '-'.

Eg : `<button type='button' onClick='return CounterUpdate("+")'>+</Button>`

> ```
> function CounterUpdate(action) {
>     var counter = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
>     var parsed = parseInt(counter);
>     var result =parsed ;
>     if(action=='+')
>     {
>       result = parsed +1;
>     }
>     else if(action=='-')
>     {
>       result = parsed -1;
>     }
>     document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = result;
> }
> ```